# spring boot using @RequestMapping("/xxx.jsp") return 404

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, request-mapping

I build an application with pure restful interface, do not have any jsp page.

I had a controller with RequestMapping annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/xxx.jsp")
```

when I request with `http://localhost:8080/xxx.jsp`，it return 404 and redirect to `/error`.

ps: I am sure `http://localhost:8080/mappings` has the mapping `/xxx.jsp`, and all my own interceptors has exclude `/xxx.jsp` using `excludePathPatterns`.

Comment: Attach the Full trace to understand the exact error

Comment: @AkashYadav there'll be no useful information in error 404's stack trace, the "mapping not found" is the only piece of information it will tell you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using "/xxx" instead of "/xxx.jsp".